# How to remove access to site when the user had a previously valid cookie?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

A user had access to a .net MVC OWIN authenticated website and has a cookie that logs them in. The administrator then revokes access and resets their role to a No Access role.

How can the site detect this? Can the Cookie authentication code be updated to check only the Roles for the user in the database upon logging in? If so, can someone point me in the right direction to override this function?

**UPDATE:**

I beleive that the code below in the OWIN Startup class is what needs to be updated to intercept/override the cookie authenticaiton. What I am trying to do is to check if the user has access to the site (if the user is part of a No Access role, deny them the login).

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = context =>
                {
                    //Somehow check the users role here?
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently, OWIN controls the cookie authentication (when a user visits the site and they have a cookie). I want to override the code that runs this authentication. Can that be done using OWIN?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I ended up doing which appears to work the way I think it should work. When the OWIN cookie is read, I check the users database (I realize that this is redundant) to ensure that their access has not been revoked. If it has been revoked, I reject the cookie authentication and they are sent back to the site login screen.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = context =>
                {
                    string userName = context.Identity.Name;
                    User user = userRepository.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
                    if(user.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == "No Access") != null)
                    {
                        context.RejectIdentity();
                    }
                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From my testing, this appears to work. I think there is probably a better, less redundant solution to this, but I haven't come across it. I believe that this code runs with every page load which is what worries me a bit. I'll probably post another question later asking if there is a better way to do this, but for now, this works.

Mark C's response really helped me tailor my search on this subject, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to "delete" the user's cookies so that they are logged out. Then when they log in again, they'll have the new permissions.

I say "delete", because you don't actually delete the cookie, but make it invalid - typically by setting it's date in the past.

This code from the MSDN will set the expiry date of the cookie to one day in the past:

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx)

Comment: What confuses me is that the cookie is on their machine, not mine. I can't do anything with the cookie in their browser. Does that make sense? I need to intercept the login from the cookie. At least, that is my understanding.

Comment: Cookies are stored on the user's machine, otherwise they can't send them to you. You then send them back a cookie with the same identifier, and it overwrites the one in their browser.

Comment: @CamilleSévigny from what I understand you rewrite the cookie just before it gets used so that it's now invalid

Comment: Although I didn't include it in the question title, I did in the question itself. I am looking for a solution using the OWIN authentication framework.